# ORA 01407 - Error - Cannot update to NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, nhibernate

My problem is that i have two entities (Document and Attach) that has an relationship one-to-one. In my app, i can save first the Document and lately if i want, i can attach an archive to it, that will be on the table Attach.

The error occurs when i have an object Document already inserted in database and then i try to add an attach on it.

Below is the nhibernate mapping:

Document.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Sigre.Business"
                   namespace="Sigre.Business.BusinessEntity">

  <class name="Document" lazy="false" table="grsds.documento_fcdr">
    
    <id name="Code" type="int" unsaved-value="0" column="docf_sq_documento_fcdr">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">grsds.sq_docf_sq_documento_fcdr</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="Nome" type="AnsiString"  length="100" not-null="true" column="docf_nm_documento_fcdr" />

    <many-to-one name="Manifest" class="TransportManifest" column="mtra_sq_manifesto_transporte" not-null="false" cascade="none" />

    <many-to-one name="User" class="User" column="user_id" not-null="false" cascade="none" />

    <set name="Attach" inverse="false" lazy="false" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="docf_sq_documento_fcdr" />
      <one-to-many class="Attach" />
    </set>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Attach.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Sigre.Business"
                   namespace="Sigre.Business.BusinessEntity">

  <class name="Attach" lazy="false" table="grsds.espec_documento_fcdr">

    <id name="Code" type="int" unsaved-value="0" column="docf_sq_documento_fcdr">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">Document</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="Archive" column="esdf_mm_documento_fcdr" type="BinaryBlob" not-null="true" />
    
    <one-to-one constrained="true" name="Document" access="property" />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

If i am inserting both Document and Attach together, it works. But when i have a Document created and try to insert an Attach, the following error occurs:

ORA-01407: cannot update ("GRSDS"."ESPEC_DOCUMENTO_FCDR"."DOCF_SQ_DOCUMENTO_FCDR") to NULL

What i tried:

1 - Save the Document having the attach to insert:

bmDocument.Save(document);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved this question.

When i bring the object Document from database, the attribute Attach when has no Attach, come as an empty list: {}

When i tried to add an Attach to this Document, i was overwriting the reference, like this:

Document.Attach = new List() { new Attach() };

The solution was use the method Add of the list that was brought from the database:

Document.Attach.Add( new Attach() );